# Thymeleaf + AngularJS - Spring Boot Application

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

reading many articles about Spring boot Application, use of Thymeleaf (Server side presentation) and Angular 1 (Client side) i have found different opinions.

My question is:
Can I "mix" use of Thymeleaf and Angular?
Not if it is possible, becauase it is, i want know if is correct and I can have advantages from this.

To render the idea, also something like this

Thank you

Comment: I see that i have a timelapse where Server side is rendered but $scope of angular isn't yet...maybe the example is not correct, but maybe there can be other valid mix...